# ParametricNDSolve computation time is sensitive to the range of independent variable

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, debugging, infinite-loop, computational-complexity

My code to solve a system of nonlinear differential equations are the following:

```
q := 1; minlna := Log[10^(-6)]; maxlna := 0; yi := 10^(-5); 
f[lna_, m_, n_, xi_] := ((-n)*m*Sqrt[3/2]*x[lna]*y[lna])/((yi^2/y[lna]^2)*((1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2)/(1 - xi^2 - yi^2))*E^(3*(lna - minlna)))^(1/n) + y[lna]*(3/2)*(2*x[lna]^2 + q*(1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2)); 
g[lna_, m_, n_, xi_] := -3*x[lna] + (n*m*Sqrt[3/2]*y[lna]^2)/((yi^2/y[lna]^2)*((1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2)/(1 - xi^2 - yi^2))*E^(3*(lna - minlna)))^(1/n) + x[lna]*(3/2)*(2*x[lna]^2 + q*(1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2));
ode1 = Derivative[1][y][lna] == f[lna, m, n, xi];
ode2 = Derivative[1][x][lna] == g[lna, m, n, xi]; ic = {x[minlna] == xi, y[minlna] == yi}; 
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x, y}, {lna, minlna, maxlna}, {m, n, xi}]; 
ysol[lna_, m_, n_, xi_] := y[m, n, xi][lna] /. sol; 
xsol[lna_, m_, n_, xi_] := x[m, n, xi][lna] /. sol; 
ParametricPlot[{xsol[lna, 0.1, 2, 0], ysol[lna, 0.1, 2, 0]}, {lna, maxlna, minlna}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

and it works. But when I want to change the range of lna slightly, lets say from lna$\in$(minlna,maxlna) to (minlna,maxlna+1) Mathematica just keeps running the code without a result.

What might be the problem?

Comment: There are complex numbers during evaluation. Therefore, use `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{xsol[lna, 0.1, 2, 0], ysol[lna, 0.1, 2, 0]} // Re], {lna, 
  maxlna, minlna}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]`

Comment: yes it works. How did you find out that it was due to complex numbers?

Comment: We can check table `Table[{xsol[lna, 0.1, 2, 0], ysol[lna, 0.1, 2, 0]} , {lna, 
  minlna, maxlna, 0.01}]` used to plot parametric curve.